# Replace main menu block with nice menus

Tags: navigation

I am using Bootstrap theme, attempting to build a basic skeleton site that will use Nice Menus dropdown. Cannot get it to work: if putting in a block it displays alongside main menu, if disabling block and enabling Nice Menu 1 in Structure -> Blocks it does not behave correctly, no dropdown on hover

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nice menu works in same way as you required. Did you configured this module correctly?

First you need to look into configuration of this module([Nice menus](http://sd6e2348d212a533.s3.simplytest.me/admin/config/user-interface/nice_menus)).

After that you need to configure your nice module correctly in block list as in attached image. If still error persists then look for JS error.[image]